# Json - Date not showing in correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

When i fetch date from the `db` it is in following format :-

`{5/13/2002 12:00:00 AM}`

When i pass this as Json, i bind it to textbox & it shows me like this :-

`/Date(1021228200000)/`

How to display date in any correct format?

Extending this question I want to bind the `date` to `html5 datepicker`, How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonDate = "/Date(1021228200000)/";
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

The substr function takes out the "/Date(" part, and the parseInt function gets the integer and ignores the ")/" at the end. The resulting number is passed into the Date constructor.

**[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)** is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly.

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)**

Comment: Now it is displaying date in textbox like this :- `"1980-12-04T18:30:00.000Z"`

Comment: var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));

Comment: var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
var date_string = date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDate();
or you can use time.js library for date format

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below to display datetime and bind date to html5 datepicker.

```
<input class='selector' id='datepicker'/>
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```